# Google charts, I can't change bars color

Tags: javascript

I need to change the colors of the bars to red and blue. Red for the limit, blue for mining. An array with data is connected to the script. I was able to customize everything except the color

```
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(regiondata);
  
  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Реализация по годам',
      subtitle: 'График реализации и добычи',
      width: 100,
    },

    bars: 'vertical',
    vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
    height: 280,
    width: 610,
    colors: ['red', 'blue'],
    backgroundColor: '#F9F6F0',
    
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('content-graf'));

  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#coloring-bars), you can do it this way :

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
  ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333'],            // RGB value
  ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver'],            // English color name
  ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
  ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2' ], // CSS-style declaration
]);
```